# jasmine test angular.element(document).ready

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have questions concerning how to test the code inside element(document).ready(), during the debug, it seems that the it'll first get to document.ready and then go to the tests and then go inside to the document.ready. I even tried to test in afterEach and find out that the code inside document.ready even happens after the afterEach. Is there any good way to do this kind of test?

I also added the document.ready inside the jasmine tests.

```
describe('test',function(){
    beforeEach(....)
    it('test',function(){
        angular.element(document).ready(function(){
            expect(test).toBe(true);
        })
    })
})
```

And in the debug mode it'll goes inside. But when the test runs, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you should use document.ready, because all angular code will execute when document ready as default.

Second, to test this kind of function, you should make the function as a service, then test that service,  and in the callback, just call that service.

Comment: After doing some research I think you're right, it's not testable to test the code inside document.ready in jasmine. But my code is inside the directive and I want to test the directive. I think the only way is to extract all the code into another file and test it.

Comment: You are right. and "another file" should be a angular service